# Cable having a coil like loop

Tags: electromagnetism

Is this ok? Or should we avoid using a loop like this

3 phase cables connecting from an isolater to terminals.
 The cables have a coil like loop in them.. a single loop to make it less stressed because the distance between the two is very limited.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI6Ag.jpg

Comment: The only potential down sides would be additional voltage drop and cost of the slightly longer cables.  Given that the cables are so short, these are probably not worth worrying about.  Putting in the loop also reduces the measurement precision required to make the cables.

Answer (score 1):

This is OK.

It perhaps looks untidy.

With thick cables like that, and closely spaced terminals, it's essential to have an extra length of cable between them so the cable is flexible enough to be able to actually get it into the terminals.

At mains frequencies, the extra inductance of that loop, in the air, is insignificant.

In electrical distribution, the extra resistance of that loop is insignificant, compared to the other resistances in the path.